# Arduino: Why Do These Two Loops Give Different Results?

Tags: for-loop, arduino, arduino-uno

I've run into a strange problem. To my knowledge these two pieces of arduino code should give the same result, but they don't. I will paste the entire arduino sketch and then paste the two pieces of code that are behaving this way.

averageValue1 and averageValue2 are supposed to calculate the average value of the last 5 readings from two potentiometers.

For some reason, when I calculate the value of BOTH variables in one for-loop, the two values seem to affect one another. Meaning the higher averageValue2 is, the higher averageValue1 is as well. However, if I calculate the two variables in two separate for-loops the result is correct, and the values don't seem to affect each other.

I'm almost certain that this change in code shouldn't affect the result, but can someone please tell me why this happens?

This is the entire code sketch:

```
    /*
  Analog input, analog output, serial output

  Reads an analog input pin, maps the result to a range from 0 to 255
  and uses the result to set the pulsewidth modulation (PWM) of an output pin.
  Also prints the results to the serial monitor.

  The circuit:
   potentiometer connected to analog pin 0.
   Center pin of the potentiometer goes to the analog pin.
   side pins of the potentiometer go to +5V and ground
   LED connected from digital pin 9 to ground

  created 29 Dec. 2008
  modified 9 Apr 2012
  by Tom Igoe

  This example code is in the public domain.

*/

// These constants won't change.  They're used to give names
// to the pins used:
const int analogInPin1 = A0;  // Analog input pin that the potentiometer is attached to
const int analogInPin2 = A1;  // Analog input pin that the potentiometer is attached to
const int analogInPin3 = A2;  // Analog input pin that the potentiometer is attached to
const int analogOutPin = 9; // Analog output pin that the LED is attached to

int sensorValue1 = 0;        // value read from the pot
int sensorValue2 = 0;        // value read from the pot
int sensorValue3 = 0;        // value read from the pot

int outputValue1 = 0;        // value output to the PWM (analog out)
int outputValue2 = 0;        // value output to the PWM (analog out)
int outputValue3 = 0;        // value output to the PWM (analog out)

void setup() {
  // initialize serial communications at 9600 bps:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

int averageCount = 5;
int lastFiveValues1 [5];
int lastFiveValues2 [5];
int averageValue1;
int averageValue2;

void loop() {

  // read the analog in value:
  sensorValue1 = analogRead(analogInPin1);
  sensorValue2 = analogRead(analogInPin2);
  sensorValue3 = analogRead(analogInPin3);


  // map it to the range of the analog out:
  outputValue1 = map(sensorValue1, 0, 1023, 140, -140);
  outputValue2 = map(sensorValue2, 0, 1023, 140, -140);
  outputValue3 = map(sensorValue3, 0, 1023, 140, -140);

  averageValue1 = 0;
  averageValue2 = 0;
  for (int loop = averageCount; loop > 0 ; loop--) {
    lastFiveValues1[loop] = lastFiveValues1[loop - 1];
    averageValue1 += lastFiveValues1[averageCount - loop];
  }
  for (int loop = averageCount; loop > 0 ; loop--) {
    lastFiveValues2[loop] = lastFiveValues2[loop - 1];
    averageValue2 += lastFiveValues2[averageCount - loop];
  }
  lastFiveValues1[0] = outputValue1;
  lastFiveValues2[0] = outputValue2;

  averageValue1 = averageValue1 / averageCount;
  averageValue2 = averageValue2 / averageCount;

  /*  // change the analog out value:
    analogWrite(analogOutPin, outputValue1);
    analogWrite(analogOutPin, outputValue2);
    analogWrite(analogOutPin, outputValue3);*/

  // print the results to the serial monitor:
  String outputString = (String)averageValue1 + " " + averageValue2;
  Serial.println(outputString);

  // wait 2 milliseconds before the next loop
  // for the analog-to-digital converter to settle
  // after the last reading:
  delay(50);
}
```

This is the two versions of the for-loop:

1 (gives correct result)

```
  averageValue1 = 0;
  averageValue2 = 0;
  for (int loop = averageCount; loop > 0 ; loop--) {
    lastFiveValues1[loop] = lastFiveValues1[loop - 1];
    averageValue1 += lastFiveValues1[averageCount - loop];
    lastFiveValues2[loop] = lastFiveValues2[loop - 1];
    averageValue2 += lastFiveValues2[averageCount - loop];
  }

  lastFiveValues1[0] = outputValue1;
  lastFiveValues2[0] = outputValue2;

  averageValue1 = averageValue1 / averageCount;
  averageValue2 = averageValue2 / averageCount;
```

2 (gives the wrong result)

```
  averageValue1 = 0;
  averageValue2 = 0;
  for (int loop = averageCount; loop > 0 ; loop--) {
    lastFiveValues1[loop] = lastFiveValues1[loop - 1];
    averageValue1 += lastFiveValues1[averageCount - loop];
    lastFiveValues2[loop] = lastFiveValues2[loop - 1];
    averageValue2 += lastFiveValues2[averageCount - loop];
  }

  lastFiveValues1[0] = outputValue1;
  lastFiveValues2[0] = outputValue2;

  averageValue1 = averageValue1 / averageCount;
  averageValue2 = averageValue2 / averageCount;
```

To me it seems like these two versions of the for-loop should give the same result, but they don't. How can this be?

Thanks guys

Comment: `for (int loop = averageCount; loop > 0 ; loop--) {` You are accessing the array past the end. This is not allowed. Valid indexes in this case would be `[0-4]`

Comment: You also might consider using a [ring buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) for this.

Comment: Thank you @JohnnyMopp that has fixed the problem. That seems like a really strange concequence of using invalid array indexes... Like I said, for some reason the value of the one variable would affect the other before I fixed the problem. That makes no sense to me. But it sure fixed the problem. Thanks!